# simple jquery pop to extrernal site

Tags: jquery, html, popup, javascript

I can't seem to find a way to do a simple popup to an external site without adding other .js files.

I have this function so far:

```
function open() {
    $('#open').html('<img src="/images/ajax-loader.gif" width="150" height="19"/></p>');
    //popup!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the standard [window.open()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp) function from the [window object](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_window.asp). It will open a new window.

```
$('#open').html('<img src="/images/ajax-loader.gif" width="150" height="19"/></p>');
//popup
var win = window.open("URL GOES HERE");
if(!win){
    alert("popup blocked")
}
return false;
```

If the browser has popup blocker enabled then you have to check for that and give an alert for the user.

Answer (score 0):

Just use standard javascript:

```
window.open(URL,name,specs,replace)
```

Answer (score 0):

You use a standard javascript window open:

```
$('#open')
    .html('<img src="/images/ajax-loader.gif" width="150" height="19"/></p>')
    .click(function(){
        window.open("URL GOES HERE");
        return false;
    });
```